# Collection efficiency of mirror

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, geometry, photonics, imaging

I want to compare plane and parabolic mirror for collection of photon from a point source. Intuitively, parabolic mirror focuses all rays from point source and gives parallel rays therefore has a higher collection efficiency. How do I mathematically prove it? Can someone help in estimating solid angle for both the cases? The mirrors have a height of 1.7mm and width of 4.3mm. The sample is placed around 1.05mm from mirror surface. And focal length in case of parabolic mirror is 0.75mm. How to calculate the efficiency analytically.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.